# How to create a spring boot annotation that converts PathVariable/RequestParam from 1 primitive to another

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, annotations, obfuscation

The code would look something like this:

```
// {accountID} will be a String such as "Ao93Fbs"
@RequestMapping(path = "/{accountID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object testFunction(@ChangeFromStringToLong @PathVariable("accountID") long accountID) {
// some code here
}
```

Focus on the @ChangeFromStringToLong.

I want to send a parameter or a path variable that will be an obfuscated String, and turn it into a long value so it can be used in the rest of the function. Is it possible?

I've created a converter but for that I have to map it to a custom object, but I'd like to to be mapped to a primitive right there in the annotation.

So all in all, is there a way to make an annotation so that even thought you send a request with a string, the variable will be a long after some processing?

Comment: You're looking for `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, and you might read the source of `PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver` for an example.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.